# Using Discord.js to check the url of an image in an embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, embed, discord, discord.js

### The idea

What I seek to do, is upon a message being sent, if that message is an embed, I want my bot to check the image in that embed (if there is one) for it's url, and if the url matches a specific url I provide, for the bot to send a specific message that I provide.

### The issue

While I know the event for messages being sent (`client.on("message", function(message) {`)
I have *no* idea how to have the bot check to see if that message is an embed, and how to have it check the url of the image in that embed, if there is one.

Comment: Users can also upload photos as attachments - wouldn't you also want to check for the url of attachments?

Answer (score 2):

If you subscribe the event `client.on("message")`, you'll recieve all the [Messages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) the bot can read.
With [message.embeds](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds) you'll get an array with all of the embeds on that message.
With [MessageEmbed](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed) you can look at messageEmbed.thumbnail or messageEmbed.image depending on which one you want, and get the url out of it.

```
client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.embeds.length > 0){
        var embed = message.embeds[0];
        if(embed.image && embed.image.url == "myurl.com"){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Something along those lines.